# How do you set the startup page for debugging in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do you start debugging the application at the application root? For example: **http://localhost:49742/**

I'm always getting a page which doesn't exist, such as:
**http://localhost:49742/Views/Home/About.aspx**

Note that it would be OK to start at **http://localhost:49742/Views/Home/About**

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821796/visual-studio-asp-net-mvc-undo-set-as-start-page-action

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Go to your project's properties and set the start page property.

1. Go to the project's *Properties*
2. Go to the *Web* tab
3. Select the *Specific Page* radio button
4. Type in the desired url in the *Specific Page* text box

Comment: @Mark- here is a good link that describes the process in more detail- http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-17-how-to-run-an-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx. I'd put that in your answer.

Comment: +1 Be sure to **type it in** on step 4.  Selecting with the [...] button will create a bogus URL :D

Comment: If you are just testing and working with the default MVC project template in VS.NET 2010, just *clear out* any value for the start page, and then debug your project. This will take you to the main "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!" page.

Comment: In addition to the above steps, you also need to make sure that you've properly selected the startup PROJECT (it's not enough to set up the default page if you have multiple projects). Right-click the Project in Solution Explorer and set it as the Startup project. The project name will then be bolded in the Solution tree.

Comment: @Mark- on step 4 you can leave the text box blank and make sure the  Specific Page radio button is selected and it will start debugging at the application root.

Answer (score 24):

While you can have a default page in the MVC project, the more conventional implementation for a default view would be to use a default controller, implememented in the global.asax, through the 'RegisterRoutes(...)' method. For instance if you wanted your Public\Home controller to be your default route/view, the code would be:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Public", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

For this to be functional, you are required to have have a set Start Page in the project.

Comment: Wow... This actually work EVEN after publishing on a server (which is not the case for accepted answer, at least, not for me) so this is the actual good answer

Comment: This is the most valid answer to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

This works for me under Specific Page for MVC:

```
/Home/Index
```

Update: Currently, I just use a forward slash in the "Specific Page" textbox, and it takes me to the home page as defined in the routing:

```
/
```

Comment: Nice simple answer.  But beware - if you've entered something similar as the Start URL, you'll still get the invalid URL message (even if this isn't currently selected).  So select Start URL, delete text in it, THEN set the Specific Page property to the relative path as above.

Answer (score 7):

Selecting a specific page from Project properties does not solve my problem.

In MVC 4 open  App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

For example, if you want to change startup page to **Login**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "",        // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Account", action = "Login"}  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start at the "application root" as you describe right click on the top level Default.aspx page and choose set as start page. Hit F5 and you're done.

If you want to start at a different controller action see Mark's answer.

Comment: Does this work for MVC?  For me, it tries to start the ASPX page and doesn't route.

Answer (score 1):

Revisiting this page and I have more information to share with others.

**Debugging environment (using Visual Studio)**

1a) Stephen Walter's link to set the startup page on MVC using the project properties is only applicable when you are debugging your MVC application.

1b) Right mouse click on the .aspx page in Solution Explorer and select the "Set As Start Page" behaves the same.

Note: in both the above cases, the startup page setting is only recognised by your Visual Studio Development Server. It is not recognised by your deployed server.

**Deployed environment**

2a) To set the startup page, assuming that you have not change any of the default routings, change the content of /Views/Home/Index.aspx to do a "Server.Transfer" or a "Response.Redirect" to your desired page.

2b)  Change your default routing in your global.asax.cs to your desired page.

Are there any other options that the readers are aware of? Which of the above (including your own option) would be your preferred solution (and please share with us why)?