# Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC undo set as start page action

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an web application that I'm working on, it was working fine until my curiosity got the better of me and I right-clicked on a view and chose Set As Start Page option.  Now, whenever I run my application it takes me to the Resource Not Found error page.  I have the default register route set in my Global config route which was working fine before.  I notice that the URL now reads:

http://localhost:1234/Views/User/Login.aspx

instead of

http://localhost:1234/

like it was before.  I'm not sure how to undo this action or what was changed, I've looked in my web.config file but I'm not sure what to look for exactly, Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can set it in the `Specific Page` option in the project properties, just leave the text box empty.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify this - select Specific Page and then leave the text box blank, don't enter "/" otherwise the project will start-up at http://localhost:1234///

Answer (score 16):

Right click your project in **Visual Studio -> Properties -> Web (left hand tab) -> Specific Page** with an empty string as the name.

Comment: I get this error : The start URL specified is not valid.. the format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: it should be empty string instead of '/'

Comment: Should be noted that some may have an .sln with multiple projects in it, so right-clicking the web project in question then selecting Properties is another way to view the Web tab and set the Specific Page to empty string

Answer (score 0):

Select the specific page then right click on it and select exclude from project,
after that again right click on that page and select include in project.
It works for me.

Comment: This option worked for me, although the second step was not as simple as right-clicking on the page and selecting Include in Project.  When I chose to Exclude the file, it disappeared from Visual Studio 2022.  I had to go into the File Explorer to locate the file, then drag and drop it into the proper location in Visual Studio.  This may be something that was updated in recent versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, changing the StartUp Project and then setting it to your main project again can help solve this. But only when you have multiple projects in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this thread is quite old, but I have just gone through the same process of trying to change my startup page. I tried to change my startup page to `Views/Home/Login.cshtml` which reported page not found.
my root was `http://localhost:63786/` and on startup the site was navigating to `http://localhost:63786/Views/Home/Login.cshtml`.

After a lot of fiddling about I realised that the root already took me to /Views/ so the startup path I actually needed was Home/Login.cshtml. This still did not work, then I realised that it was leaving the file extension in the path and it should not be. So the startup path should have been Home/Login.

The automatically selected path generated from the ellipsis is incorrect, check that the path is generated correctly and remove the extension and then it should work.