# What is this exception when I attempt to debug my MVC4 website

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-4

Every now and again when I attempt to debug my website, I get an exception telling me that a resource that I know exists, and has existed since I started my project, is missing?  Is something caching or not caching in my Dev environments webserver or something that I am unaware of?  Has anyone else run into an issue like this???? Here is a picture of what it says is missing along with the file actually in project.[image]

As you can clearly see, I the file is in my successfully built project, but when I attempt to navigate there it gives me this error exception.  Let me be clear as well, This site was work and it does work every now and then.  The way I resolve this issue is that I rebuild the entire solution.  It works for a while, then I get this exception again.

Comment: The project file sometimes give me similar heartburn when it does not include the file correctly. Try "Exclude from project" and then "Include in Project" the particular View

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you start debugging with the active window being the view and no default startup page for the project.  See this SO post for how to set the default startup page - [Visual Studio ASP.Net MVC undo set as start page action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821796/visual-studio-asp-net-mvc-undo-set-as-start-page-action)