# Visual Studio 2012 stop debugging open page

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I know this is a stupid question, but I must be Googling on the wrong search params...

When I am in VS 2012, if I am currently changing the code on a given web page (e.g. cshtml, aspx) and press F5, the website attempts to run the application starting at my current page that I am editing, as opposed to running default start page for the site.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Right click your default page and click on set as start page.

Answer (score 0):

I should have mentioned that this is an MVC project. However I found the answer here:

[How do you set the startup page for debugging in an ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333002/how-do-you-set-the-startup-page-for-debugging-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

You should have setup the current page you are editing as a startup page. To make the default page as startup page, just edit the .csproj file in notepad and set the startpageurl tag empty.

[image: Startpageurl tag should be like]