# Is there a way to change VS behavior to browse to currently opened in editor view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

During developing ASP.Net sites, especially MVC, **especially** partial views when you run website in Visual Studio default site to browse is currently opened in editor view. It's really starting to irritate me, because when I develop SPA applications those views doesn't have  much sense on their own. Is there a way to turn off this "feature"? This way always VS will open a default home address set in routing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do you set the startup page for debugging in an ASP.NET MVC application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1333002/1260215)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it was the same issue. Thanks for help!