# Start application a specific route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to start my .NET MVC application at the following route

http://example.com/settings

How do I force my app to route to this when it starts up?

Comment: [These answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333002/how-do-you-set-the-startup-page-for-debugging-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) may help

Comment: I actually want the first action that loads to be /settings, I do not want to change the application root url.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make it clear exactly what you want and in what context.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? if it is version 4, you can change the default routing in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "settings", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I don't want any routing except for the one route /settings. The rest of the app will be SPA

Comment: what do you mean by SPA? in asp.net mvc action listener will be triggered by the routing (url address).

Comment: There will be one route using .NET MVC namely /settings which will write files to disk, after which the rest of the app will be angular single page application.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your route settings.
For example, you have DefaultController and your App_Start/RouteConfig.cs contains:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Your DefaultController must contains:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
  return Redirect("/settings");
}
```

Comment: This won't work I cannot have the default route with {controller}/{action}/{id} as there is a single page app using hashes which will then match this route (as hashes aren't sent to the server) for example /#route1, /#route2 will all resolve to the default route on the server :(