# Remove authentication in ASP.net MVC single page application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, single-page-application

I am trying to play about with the asp.net MVC SPA template in visual studio 2013, I don't need any of the authentication bits, I just need to load directly onto one of the controllers pages.

How do I get rid of all the authentication stuff from the initial template?

Comment: have you considered <authentication mode="None" /> in web.config?
here is more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: How do I set the entry point to the view I want?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333002/how-do-you-set-the-startup-page-for-debugging-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application, or you could look at maproute (If am not mistaken, been a while since I last used VC/MVC)

Comment: Slowly getting there, it no longer wants to go to the login page, and my default home page pops up for a second but then it tries to find "account/authorize" (which I had deleted because I don't want this built in authorization) I cannot find a reference to that controller in the existing code :/

Answer (score 24):

Remove the `[Authorize]` annotation from `HomeController` and remove this:

```
@section Scripts{
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
}
```

from `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` because one of does `js` is causing the redirect to the login page even after removing the `[Authorize]` annotation from `HomeController` and probably you don't need it. If you need these scripts in your page, then you need to edit one of them.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I did.

Remove `[Authorize]` attribute from the home controller.

Then in `app.viewmodel.js` you'll see this:

```
self[options.bindingMemberName] = ko.computed(function () {
    if (!dataModel.getAccessToken()) {
        // The following code looks for a fragment in the URL to get the access token which will be
        // used to call the protected Web API resource
        var fragment = common.getFragment();

        if (fragment.access_token) {
            // returning with access token, restore old hash, or at least hide token
            window.location.hash = fragment.state || '';
            dataModel.setAccessToken(fragment.access_token);
        } else {
            // no token - so bounce to Authorize endpoint in AccountController to sign in or register
            window.location = "/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
        }
    }

    return self.Views[options.name];
});
```

This is the section that will redirect you to the login screen, so comment out or remove the `if` block. If you want you can also go into `app.datamodel.js` and remove or comment out `self.getAccessToken`.

In addition, in `WebApiConfig.cs` you will probably want to remove / comment out the following lines:

```
// Web API configuration and services
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it. I just removed the

Removed the [Authorize] annotation from HomeController.cs (got this from Castro Roy's answer). Even after this the app redirected to the login page.

To resolve the redirection remove the [Authorize] annotation from the AccountController.cs

However I have retained the authentication related code so that can be used in other pages.

Answer (score 2):

Put `[AllowAnonymous]` at the beginning of the function you want to allow anonymous access to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing `[Authorize]` from the controllers, the file home.viewmodel.js is causing the redirect problem on the home page load.  In `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`, remove the line `~/Scripts/app/home.viewmodel.js` from the `bundles/app` ScriptBundle.

Comment: why does it trigger authorization ?