# asp.net, MVC filepath problems. Appended file ending

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I execute my MVC project, the page that tries to load has the **.cshtml ending** in it still. It also adds /viewpath/ to the beginning of the path. So the first page that tries to load is for instance: `http://localhost:63250/Views/TileModels/Index.cshtml` when it *should* be `http://localhost:63250/`

It doesn't matter which page I set as default, the first page always results in a bad url and 404 error.

I know I've messed something up in my project, but I just can't seem to figure out *what*..

I just made a new project to experiment a bit and I get the same kind of problem the second I hit "Set As Start Page" on some page. At least now I have something more to google for!

Comment: Do you have any strange redirects? Try doing a search for the name of the file it ends up trying to redirect you to and see if it's anywhere in your code.

Comment: @mason That comes up with nothing.. Just edited the question a bit, it seems I get the same error when setting the start page on something else than the default...

Comment: Ah. In MVC you can't set the start page to a Razor view. You need to set it to something based on the routes you've defined. Your request will be mapped to a controller based on the [routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing), and the controller will be responsible for returning the view.

Comment: You are correct. I set the start page through project properties and now it works like it should! 
Thank you for the help! (I answered my own question but now it says I can't accept the answer before 2 days.. something I can do about this?)

Comment: No, you can't accept your own question until after 2 days. Anyways, if your question is a duplicate of that one, we should vote to close it as such instead of having a separate answer here.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the help, a bit new to posting on this site! :)

Answer (score 0):

After finding out that setting the start page caused the problem, I managed to find the solution by googling a bit more!

This answers my exact question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1333024/4640922

Set the start page through project properties, not by setting a .cshtml file!