# How to oraganise mvc Area Routing in Correct Manner

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here i have one main Route and one Area Rote.
**MainRoute**

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default2",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

**AreaRoute**

```
 context.MapRoute(
              "Employee_default",
              "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              new {Controller="EmployeeHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
```

When i Press **ctrl+F5**  its Ruiing Area Rote How can i make Main route as statrtup Route

Comment: You can do it via project properties check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/1333024/5621827

Comment: if i want Department/Index then its showing page cant find