# Application start page url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is an application on asp.net mvc. And such an interesting moment. There is a start page which is the default configuration in the route. And when you start the application, it writes only localhost ... How to ensure that the default page prescribe its full path like everyone else, i.e. localhost / Controller / Action.
[image]

Tell me how to achieve this? I nned like:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

My RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Authorization", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Your site happens to launch `localhost` which, as your RouteConfig shows is defaulted to `Home/Index`. If you went to `Home/Index` that would show in your browser - both resolve to the same route. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1333024/3832895 - you just need to change startup page for your site

Comment: @thisextendsthat thanks. It, works.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of the "default" route is having something to show the user when no route is filled in. People that will visit your site won't type in or find "www.yoursite.com/authorization/index" so that's why the routing configures a default route.

If you want your page to show something different by default you need to change the data in the default route in your routes.config and create a controller for it. You could also let the default land at an action that only redirects to "authorization/index" which will change the URL.

Lastly you could simply fix it with some javascript on the page, but I think this will also cause a page reload so fixing it server side is probably best.